# Explode array values only if they contain specific symbol

Tags: php, arrays

I have Array like this

```
Array
(
    [keywords] => Array
        (
            [1] => Hazmat - Fuel/Oil/Gas
            [2] => Marine Life Incident
            [3] => Bird - Avian Incident
            [4] => Missing Child / Child Abduction
        )
)
```

I want to explode only those keywords which is contain "**-**" and store them in new array with remaining keywords.

Like this

```
Array
    (
        [newkeywords] => Array
            (
                [1] => Hazmat
                [2] => Fuel/Oil/Gas
                [3] => Bird
                [4] => Avian Incident
                [5] => Marine Life Incident
                [6] => Missing Child / Child Abduction

            )
    )
```

Any idea how can I check every array value which is contain dash and explode them. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: It's quite basic fundamental PHP, solvable if php manual is properly read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this below code...

```
     $keywords= array("Hazmat - Fuel/Oil/Gas","Marine Life Incident","Bird - Avian Incident");
             foreach($keywords as $keyword){
               $isTwoArr=  explode("-", $keyword);
               if(count($isTwoArr)>1){
                   foreach($isTwoArr as $oneArr)
                      $newArr[]=$oneArr;
               }
               else{
                    $newArr[]=$keyword;
               }
            }
 print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score 3):

First, declare your new array.
Next, write a loop to check each element in your existing array. 
In the loop have an `if` statement using `strpos()` to find the position of the '-' in each element of the array.
If '-' is found use `array_push($newarray, $newValues)` to send to the new array.
Else push the entire value to the new array.

Here is some mock code. This gives you an idea of the structure of the code you are looking for.

```
<?php
$keywords = array(
    [1] => Hazmat - Fuel/Oil/Gas
    [2] => Marine Life Incident
    [3] => Bird - Avian Incident
    [4] => Missing Child / Child Abduction
);

$newkeywords = [];

for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($kewords); $i++) {
    if (strpos($keywords[i+1], "-") === true) {
        //split the string in two and push to new array
        //explode() creates a new array
        $keywordChunks = explode("-", $keywords[i]);
        array_push($newkeywords, $keywordChunks[0];
        array_push($newkeywords, $keywordChunks[1]);
    } else {
        //push the entire word to the new array
        array_push($newkeywords, $keywords[i]);
    }
}
?>
```